# Build of Julia fails on OS X with llvm-config error

Tags: llvm, julia, macos-sierra

I have been trying to build Julia the whole day in MacOS Sierra. Finally after sorting out a lot of problems I'm stuck at this.

```
/bin/sh: llvm-config: command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
make[1]: llvm-config: Command not found
    CC src/APInt-C.o
In file included from /Users/sudoankit/github/julia/src/APInt-C.cpp:3:
./llvm-version.h:3:10: fatal error: 'llvm/Config/llvm-config.h' file not found
#include <llvm/Config/llvm-config.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [APInt-C.o] Error 1
make: *** [julia-src-release] Error 2
```

I have updated everything and also installed `llvm` using `brew`. 
Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: `brew` typically puts the llvm binaries in `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`, you can try adding that to your path

Comment: Julia uses it's own LLVM installation, as it typically requires some custom patches. Try `make -C deps distclean-llvm` to wipe your LLVM install and start over.